# NewsFeed with Redis At Scale Stratagy

Tags: php, mysql, redis

I'm running into an interesting dilema while trying to solve a scale problem.

Current we have a social platform that has a pretty typical feed. We are using a graph database and each time a feed is requested by the user we hit the DB. While this is fine now, it will come to a grinding halt as we grow our user base. Enter Redis.

Currently we store things like comments, likes and such in individual Redis keys in JSON encoded strings by post ID and update them when there are updates, additions or deletes. Then in code we loop through the DB results of posts and pull in the data from the Redis store. This is causing multiple calls to Redis to construct each post, which is far better than touching the DB each time. The challenge is keeping up with changing data such as commenter's/liker's avatars, Screen Names, closed accounts, new likes, new comments etc associated with each individual post.

I am trying to decide on a strategy to handle this the most effective way. Redis will only take us so far since we will top out at about 12 gig of ram per machine.

One of the concepts in discussion is to use a beacon for each user that stores new post ID. So when a user shares something new, all of their connected friends' beacon get the post ID so that when the user logs in their feed is seen as Dirty requiring an update, then storing the feed by ID in a Redis Set sorted by timestamp. To retrieve the feed data we can do a single query by IDs rather than a full traversal which is hundreds of times faster. That still does not solve the interacting user's account information, their likes, and comments problem which is ever changing, but does solve in part building the feed problem.

Another idea is to store a user's entire feed (JSON encoded) in a MYSQL record and update it on the fly when the user requests it and the beacon shows a dirty feed. Otherwise it's just a single select and json decode to build the feed. Again, the dynamic components are the huddle.

Has anyone dealt with this challenge successfully, or have working knowledge of a strategy to approach this problem.

Comment: Don't have a full answer to your problem, but if you are working with JSON data already, have you looked into [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org)? I've been using it for years, and it scales incredibly well with replica sets and sharding. Redis is still going to be a faster single-key lookup time, but mongo provides flexibility to store the entire JSON data set -- seems like a better solution than storing JSON data in a MySQL record :)

Comment: I also like the idea of using MongoDB as described above, if you need further expansion, Riak may also be another option for use as it has outgoing links perty well handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use a mongodb as @solocommand has described, but you may want to stop the expectation that you "update" data on demand.  Instead push your users changes into a "write" queue, which will then update the database as needed.  Then you can load from the database (mongodb) and work with it as needed, or update the other redis records.

Moving to a messaging system Amazon SQS, IronMQ, or RabbitMQ, may help you scale better.  You can also use redis queues as a basic message bus.

Answer (score 2):

> Currently we store things like comments, likes and such in individual Redis keys in JSON encoded strings by post ID

Use more efficient serializer, like igbinary or msgpack. I suggest igbinary (check http://kiss-web.blogspot.com/)

> Then in code we loop through the DB results of posts and pull in the data from the Redis store.

Be sure to use pipelining for maximum performance.

> This is causing multiple calls to Redis to construct each post, which is far better than touching the DB each time.

Do not underestimate power of DB primary keys. Try to do the same (not join, but select by keys) with your DB:

```
 SELECT * FROM comments WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6):
```

Single redis call is faster than single DB call, but doing lots of redis calls (even pipelined) compared to one sql query on primary keys - not so much. Especially when you give your DB enough memory for buffers.

You can use DB and Redis by "caching" DB data in redis. You do something like that:

1. Every time you update data, you update it in DB and delete from Redis.
2. When fetching data, you first try to get them from Redis. If data is not found in Redis, you search them id DB and insert into Redis for future use with some expire time.

That way you store in redis only usefull data. Unused(old) data will stay only in DB.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. We've moved to a very similar approach through pipelining and mget calls to better handle the nature of more dynamic information.